# UIStoryboardSegue, hide sourceviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I have an application where it shows UICollectionViewController (v1) on launching. If I double tap on a cell, a seque (S) is performed and another view controller (v2) is opened. When the back is tapped in v2, it comes back to collection view, v1. This all works fine.

Now I have a requirement to open the app from thirdPartyApp (like from Mail). If I open a file from Mail, it should directly open the v2. I am now performing the seque S in the app delegate, it is showing v1 and then v2. Is there any way to show the v2 directly from Mail, and show v1 on hitting back button?

Thanks

Comment: set a bool variable globally like bIsLaunchOnLoad; make it true in viewdidload. now in viewWillAppear if bIsLaunchOnLoad is true perform navigation to your v2 also set bIsLaunchOnLoad to false. now when you popback to v1 from v2 in viewwillappear bIsLaunchOnLoad will be falls so do notthing hear. It might be a work arround. hope you get better idea

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work for me. Because, v1 loads on launch. viewWillAppear of v1 will be called before segue is performed. So, only after segue is performed, v2 is available

Comment: "seGue"! It has a G in it and is pronounced "seg-way" not "seek".

Answer (score 0):

Intialize viewController(V2) and set rootViewController of the Window to the ViewController you want to show (V2).